# Select element value is string

Tags: jquery, laravel, select

I am sending select element selected value through ajax to Laravel controller action and validated the value as required in controller.

The problem is I am getting select element value as string not integer. So when first option is selected which has value 0, it goes as a string ("0") to controller and does not validated as required in action method.

The options to the select element is added dynamically.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
var row_data = {
    'lob_id': lob_id,
    'sub_lob_id': sub_lob_id,
    'product_id': product_id,
};

$.ajax({
    url: '{{route('
    getProductThreshold ')}}',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: row_data,
    success: function (response) {
        loader(true);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
$validators = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lob_id' => 'required',
            'sub_lob_id' => 'required',
            'product_id' => 'required',
        ]);
```

**Controller Request**

[image]

How should I use laravel validator if value is being sent as string in request?

Comment: We can't help you debug this without actually seeing your code. However I would guess that you're just sending the value as returned from `val()`, which is a string. Try using `parseInt()` on it to force the type coercion

Comment: I tried using `parseInt()` still values are being sent as string

Comment: Are you certain that the value being sent is `"0"`, I just did a test and `"0"` passed the `required` validation. try `dd($request->all())` before your validation to see what exactly is being passed

Comment: Yes I am sure it's string. I have updated the question with request values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another laravel validation i.e `not_in:0` and that worked for me. Simply its check for request parameter if zero whether parameter is string or integer

```
$validators = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lob_id' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'sub_lob_id' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'product_id' => 'required|not_in:0',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any data sent over the internet is sent as string, and the destination parses and decodes this string the way it needs. That's why **HTTP request parameters are always string**.

When you receive a request and wait for a numeric value for a parameter, just **convert it to number before using it**. In your case, you are using Laravel PHP, you can use [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

For Laravel validator, there's a **validation rule** to check if the incoming parameter is a number or not, which is [`numeric`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-numeric). Laravel knows that the parameter is string and deals with that. The validator doesn't check the data type, but **it checks that the value of the string is a number**.

You can find the full set of Laravel validation rules here: 
[Laravel Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#available-validation-rules)

Comment: You pointed out correctly and I posted the answer with exact validation I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Use parseInt and send the data as number. Though technically the request body is sent as string, your model will see the value in it as number and will treat it like that
- Change your model on backend to parse the received string as number. But this is not recommended.